# Java game server for side scrolling space shooter

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

My friends developed this game using java and they asked me to do the multilayer for it. its a side scrolling shooter like asteroids. I know it would have to deal with sockets and id prefer to use tcp over udp to have a constant connection and not have data clusters back and forth. i have a proto-type that sends strings back and forth from client to server visa versa. but how would I implement this into a game? would I send the x and y coordinates of the ship to the game that's hosting the game then send back the other games coordinates? any help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advanced.

Comment: For a small project like yours, letting the client do lot of the calculations are probably okay, but a good advice is this: Never trust the client! All data you can receive from the client can be forged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this structure for your game:

- Create a server that hosts the game and do calculations.
- Let the server create and handle objects (ennemies) moving in the screen. This way you only have to send data server -> client to update the user interface.
- As for the space ships the server has to update all clients at the same time, so on client side, send the x,y coordinates to the server everytime there's a movement and then broadcast the new position to every player. Same goes for shooting or any other event generated client-side.
- For when two objects collide (for example a laser and an ennemy), this should be handled by the server, having both objects and ships positions.

**Clients** will only have to read objects coordinates, draw them and send ships/laser position to the server.
The **Server** will generate objects and send their position to all clients. At the same time read ships position and update users interface.
Sending/reading data can be hard tho. There are several ways to do so and depends on what it's easier for you to comprehend for now. It can be improved later.

- During the whole game the server keeps sending objects position. 
  If number of objects on screen isn't always the same, send a string containing the number of objects at the moment + their coordinates. Client side loop through those coordinates using the number you specified before.
- Same goes for the ships. I guess those will be a fixed number, so you can just send their coordinates.
- Inside the string, coordinates should be separated by something so you will be able to read them when received. 
  One way to do so is to separate them with a specific character

  ```
  "x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3;x4,y4; ..." 
  ("," between x-y and ";" between sets of coordinates)
  ```

  or, since you are sending a `String`, write them always with the same ammount of characters (say 4)

  ```
  "0012054201620104"  (x1: 12 , y1: 542 ; x2: 162 , y2: 104)
  ```
- Finaly I suggest to add a header to every packet you send, to know if it's a list of objects coordinates or a list of ship coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

WEll, this could be done in several ways, 
Let say we have object:
- Space_1,Space_2,....Space_n  as space craft objects

As the game proceeds, the screen will be filled with space craft objects
Each time you will get the x,y coordinate of all the space_x elements in the game
And you will also send your coordinate

So the game at a client machine will have 
- point1 (x,y) of your coordinate
- point_2....point_n (x,y) for other space crafts (of your opponent)
- each time it refreshes the x,y for opponents change

You will handle the shoot of the space craft in your local application
Lets say you shoot and hit space_3
You will send to the server that space_3 has been hit, hence flag this ship as dead in the server
When other clients (other users/players) get the refresh call from the server, all of them will see that space_3 has been hit

Hope this helped, also if its too abstract

Comment: so after i set up my printwriter and bufferread i write the position of ship 1 and read the position of ship 2 simultaneously? then on the next frame paint the ships and read and write again? would that do?

Comment: I have to get more from your code to make a more assertive assumption, but basically yes, this would be a good solution
You may have to do some performance adjustment with the communication to the server